# Regulations for Storing Sensative Information?

Tags: database-design

I don't think this is the correct site to post this, but I wasn't sure where else I could.

Anyway, my question is simple. Are there any federal regulations or state (Colorado) regulations for storing sensative user information such as SSN, billing and contact information? More specifically, the company I am currently doing a database audit for is a local college.

They have a lot of this information as plain text in the database and I would like to tell them not only is this a bad idea, but it could cause them legal issues if discovered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the extent that this would create regulatory issues, it would do so under the [Family Educational Rights and Privacy Act (FERPA)](http://Family%20Educational%20Rights%20and%20Privacy%20Act%20%28FERPA%29) assuming that the system does not process credit card transactions.  If it did process credit card transactions, it would fall under the auspices of [PCI compliance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard).  I'm not an expert in FERPA compliance but I don't believe that it requires that data be encrypted within the database.

That being said, you can certainly point out that FERPA would likely come into play if there was a breach (say, a backup tape was lost in transit) and the underlying data was not encrypted.  Not encrypting the data could force an embarrassing public disclosure that a breach had occurred.  If the data was all encrypted (and assuming that the encryption key was not also lost), you can generally avoid the public disclosure.

Comment: Cool, FERPA was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for taking the time with my question.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the issues in Justin Cave's answer, other state laws might affect you in Colorado. For example, Massachusetts has a statute that by its wording affects any business that stores personal data about a resident of Massachusetts. I don't know whether it's been tested in court.

There might be better summaries than [Encryption Laws and Compliance](http://www.echoworx.com/wp-content/uploads/Encryption_Laws_and_Compliance.pdf) from http://www.echoworx.com, but this one was easy for me to find. Searching "privacy laws compliance" or "compliance software" might be helpful, too.

Comment: Thanks for the state level summaries. They are a Colorado company, but I will be sure to include these in my report. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: I understand that they're a Colorado company, but Massachusetts doesn't care. If you store personal data about, say, a student who goes to college in Colorado, but is a resident of Massachusetts, Massachusetts law applies. (That's what Massachusetts says, anyway.)